# How to access VSCode live server on public wifi network?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, networking, webserver

I have set up a live server on VSCode using the Live Server extension. The live server runs on port 5500 and works fine on my local machine. However, when I try to access the hosted web page from another device on the same network, it only works if the network is set as “Private Network” in Windows. If the network is set as “Public Network”, the page does not load.

I have tried changing the inbound rules in Windows Firewall to allow all connections on port 5500, but that did not help. How can I allow other devices to access my live server on a public network?

Comment: why not use a normal web server